# Beginner Haskell multiset equality

Tags: haskell

I am making a function two check if two unordered multisets are equal.

I have a sorting function:

```
allsort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]  
allsort [] = []  
allsort (x:xs) =   
    let smallerSorted = allsort [a | a <- xs, a <= x]  
        biggerSorted = allsort [a | a <- xs, a > x]  
    in  smallerSorted ++ [x] ++ biggerSorted
```

and a equality check function:

```
iEqual :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
iEqual [] [] = True 
iEqual (x:xs) (y:ys) = x == y && iEqual xs ys
iEqual _ _ = False
```

i just dont know how to combine them into one function or call allsort within iEqual...

Then another idea is to check length and if x is subset of y.

EDIT: I solved it, just compared lengths and then if they are subsets of eachother and it works. Thank you all..

Comment: You don't need to define `iEqual`; `[a]` is already an instance of `Eq`.

Comment: @chepner This might be, I guess, an exercise/homework/whatever which includes "define your own `iEqual`" or "reuse what we have done in class".

Comment: yes we just have to finish the function given iEqual :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool

Answer (score 5):

First, declare those multisets as a proper distinct type:

```
newtype Multiset a = Multiset { getOrderedList :: [a] }
```

You want to be able to generate such sets from any list, but guarantee it's always ordered. Well,

```
fromList :: Ord a => [a] -> Multiset a
fromList = Multiset . sort
```

(Of course you can also use your custom sort function, but [the standard one](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:sort) will be more efficient.)

Now, two multisets are equal iff they are equal as ordered lists. That's convenent, because we've ensured that the list in the `Multiset` constructor *is* always ordered! So we can just do

```
instance  (Eq a) => Eq (Multiset a) where
  Multiset s == Multiset t = s == t
```

(Again, you can also use `iEqual s t` here, but the standard equality `==` is just fine.)

Note that this `Eq` instance can also be generated automatically, if you just write

```
newtype Multiset a = Multiset { getOrderedList :: [a] }
      deriving (Eq)
```

(You can also derive other useful classes, I'd suggest `Show`, `Generic` and `Functor`.)

```
Prelude> newtype Multiset a = Multiset { getOrderedList :: [a] } deriving (Eq)
Prelude> :m +Data.List
Prelude Data.List> let fromList = Multiset . sort
Prelude Data.List> fromList [4,4,3] == fromList [3,4,4]
True
Prelude Data.List> fromList [4,4,3] == fromList [3,4,5]
False
```

Comment: I should have been more clear, i am given an input iEqual [4,4,3] [3,4,4] and i need to show that they are equal (True). I am given iEqual :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool and i have to continue from there. and im not allowed to import libraries.

Comment: I don't care what you're “allowed” to do, this is not HomeworkOverflow. – Just convert both lists to a `Multiset`, with `fromList`, and compare the results with `==`. If you then feel you need to fulfill some stupid assignment limitations, you can replace `fromList` with `allSort` and `==` with `iEqual`, but it's silly.

Answer (score 2):

Since this looks as homework, I'll give a hint, only.

Suppose we want to compare strings in a case-insensitive way. We are given two functions. The first one is `sameString` which checks if two strings are equal

```
sameString :: String -> String -> Bool
sameString = (==)
```

The other one converts a string to lowercase:

```
lowerString :: String -> String
lowerString = map toLower
```

We can now combine them as follows:

```
caseInsensitiveMatch :: String -> String -> Bool
caseInsensitiveMatch s1 s2 = sameString (lowerString s1) (lowerString s2)
```

(OK, this is a big hint... ;-))